# Can I configure C++ build and run options in eclipse CDT to point to a g++ on another computer

Tags: c++, eclipse, ssh, eclipse-cdt

I have a server with a very slow connection. Hence installing eclipse on the server and taking an xwindow was not a good option.So What I attempted was to install eclipse on my client,  set up sftp via nautilus and open my c++ files on my server inside my local eclipse. This works great. But to run the files, I need several libraries that are installed in the server which would be painful to install on every client I use. I am now opening an ssh connection separately in a terminal and using it to compile and run. But I felt it would be better if it is integrated with eclipse as I can make use of eclipse's debug tools and stuff. Hence I was wondering if I can make eclipse CDT point to the server's version of G++ compiler and linker, so When I press the debug or run button on eclipse it would actually run on the server and just give me the output in eclipse's console? Is this even possible?

PS - I am not addicted to eclipse. It would be great even if you can suggest any other software that would allow me to do this. I am basically doing all this just to debug my code faster with a number of break points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it possible using Netbeans remote C++ development I found [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html). Works like a charm.